# How to use console.log() in the new NodeJS external language Cell functionality in version 12.0?

Tags: external-calls, javascript

If I type the following

[image]

Mathematica returns nothing. Requesting `Information[%]` seems to indicate that the operation `$Failed`. I have looked at the messages window and in the terminal window, but nothing seems to be  output?

Comment: What are you expecting to see? `console.log` does not return the string that it logged in javascript (it returns `undefined`), so running the code would not return something (eg, nothing would be displayed in the notebook). Do you want behaviour like `Echo` or `Print`?

Comment: After some checking, my belief is that there is no easy way to have `console.log` do something like `Echo` or `Print`. The main problem here is that `console.log` is built to have a side effect - writing to the equivalent of 'stdout' - and that stream isn't a thing you can access from the notebook interface. `console.log` doesn't return anything, and so, you don't see output.

Comment: Thx, I was away for the summer. Yes I think you are right. I was hoping to get some output from the console.log. I am happy to accept your comment as an Answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some checking, my belief is that there is no easy way to have `console.log` do something like `Echo` or `Print`. The main problem here is that `console.log` is built to have a side effect - writing to the equivalent of 'stdout' - and that stream isn't a thing you can access from the notebook interface. `console.log` doesn't return anything, and so, you don't see output.

Edit: According to [M.R.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222262/57593), this now works in 12.1.

Comment: Any chance to redirect `console.log` to `stdout`?

Comment: I checked this and it turns out `console.log` actually does write to `stdout`, but for some reason it's not picked up by the notebook. `process.stdout.write` also doesn't get caught by the notebook.

Comment: interesting. It seems one would have to check where the ZMQ socket is connecting to in the NodeJS case on the Mathematica side to figure out where things need to be written.

Comment: I wonder if `print` in Python gets caught, and if so, how.

Answer (score 2):

Console log seems to work (emits cells of type Print) in version 12.1:

[image]